# How to add products to cart from category page

Tags: php, magento

On the form in the product page ( found in `/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`) there is `action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>"`, which creates a url to add a product to the cart with the specified quantity.

However, when trying to use this to add products to the cart from the category page, the function does not return anything. What is the Mage path to use the function? For example, `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($relatedProductId);`. What is the correct way to call `getSubmitUrl()` from outside the product page?

Answer (score 0):

read this post, it could be helpfull

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/222020/

Comment: `action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"` also returns NULL